# What kind of caulk to use in order to caulk the toilet to the floor?

Tags: toilet

My toilet was replaced and it has no caulk around the bottom of it.  A little water does seep around it from time to time.  What kind of caulk should I use to do the job?  It sits on ceramic tile, and the tile is on a cement slab.

Comment: Is the water seeping out from under the toilet? Or is getting on the floor and then trying to run in under the toilet? The answers to this will have a direct impact on next steps.

Comment: Water should NOT be coming from under the toilet. Not even a drop. Please answer Michael's question so we can advice.

Answer (score 2):

It is best NOT to caulk this location.  Caulking this location can lead to moisture from a leaking toilet getting trapped under the toilet and creating a haven for mold (and/or rot, should there be wood in the area).

In your case remove the toilet, and replace the wax seal (or use one of many rubberized "no wax" products, which claim to be better.

If you do caulk the location, I recommend leaving a gap at some point, perhaps in the back of the toilet, to allow some air circulation. I prefer a quality latex caulk to silicon, as the silicon never seems to stick all that long.

Comment: +1, I wholeheartedly agree that you should **not** caulk around the base of the toilet. Any leak from the wax ring would then be unnoticeable, meaning potential for significant damage before you recognize there is a problem.

Comment: I'm also in the "do not caulk" camp, but some inspectors quote IRC SECTION P2705 -- INSTALLATION 

P2705.1 General. 
The installation of fixtures shall conform to the following: 

...
3. Where fixtures come in contact with walls and floors, the contact area shall be water tight.

Answer (score 1):

You must first repair the leak coming from the base of the toilet. Most likely the wax ring needs to be replaced. Once the leak is repaired than you can caulk the base.

The type of caulking used prominently by most installers is any good exterior latex or siliconized brand. The reason for latex is it seals very well once cured and also it is easily cleaned from non-target surfaces with a moist rag.

It is best not to use an adhesive-type caulking only because the toilet may need to be moved and gluing it to the floor will only impede its' removal.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find out where the water is coming from. Check all around and under your toilet to find the most wet spot. The water may not be coming from under the toilet but just settling there.

**If water is coming from under the toilet, you should replace the wax gasket.** **If you caulk around the base of the toilet without fixing the initial cause of the problem you will be making matters worse for yourself in the long run.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to find where the leak is if it is your wax ring replace it afterwards roll some plumber's putty very long and put around the bottom of the base of the toilet when you push down the toilet on to the flange and a wax ring the party around the outer of the toilet will squeeze out and make a sale, this would be a better option for you. Silicone caulking witches make a mess and ruin the tile underneath only when you wipe the silicone you would get it everywhere most professional plumbers used plumber putty to make a gasket like around the base of their toilets look around

Comment: Yes its up to you if you want to seal between the floor and the toilet I don't do it because  if the wax ring weeks you can have evidence of it a lot quicker but some people don't like the big gap between the toilet bottom and the floor so plumbers putty would be the best to use and leave a section behind the toilet open for evidence of water to leak through.                                  Please note: that in residential  this is not a code requirement but in commercial and industrial work you must still on the bottom of the toilet and the floor for it to pass code

Comment: Hey I read what you wrote for your question are you sure your toilet isn't sweating you just said you had it replaced if the walls of the ceramic coating of the toilet or not as thick as your old toilet you may be looking at the condensation on the toilet bowl from your cold water sitting in the tank. This condensation can swipe down on the floor and make it look like you have a major water leak you should check to see if your tank is very wet before ripping it off and doing all this work .