# Caulk around bottom of toilet?

Tags: bathroom, leak, toilet, caulk

We just got a lovely new vinyl bathroom floor put in.  The edges (wall, tub) are nicely caulked but not the base of the toilet.

I did read [What kind of caulk to use in order to caulk the toilet to the floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/80968/74694) where everybody said "don't caulk," but I'm concerned because the toilet sits three feet away from a washing machine.  The floor isn't perfectly horizontal.  It slopes slightly down toward the toilet.  The washing machine might leak, or someone might pull something wet out of the washer and drip water on the floor.  Also, another three feet in a perpendicular direction and we are looking at a bathtub with shower curtain.  More opportunities for spills.  I don't want spilled water to get under the toilet.  This was a problem previously with the washing machine I used to have (was just replaced a week ago).

At that linked question, I read that if you caulk, then you should leave a gap in the caulk around the base of the toilet.  I guess I could pick a segment that is at a maximum distance from both the washer and the tub.  Is a one inch gap enough?

---

Underneath the vinyl flooring (that was cut from a long roll at Home Depot) is plywood subflooring.  Under that is a primitive cellar.

Comment: What is the floor made of?

Comment: @kris - vinyl.....

Comment: I’m sorry I meant what is the substrate. Is the vinyl on top of concrete or wood framed floor?

Comment: https://www.familyhandyman.com/plumbing/why-you-should-caulk-your-toilet-to-the-floor/.

Comment: @kris I find the number 1 leak point for a toilet to be the wax ring. this leaks right onto the floor. So I disagree with that part of the article, you might want to sumirize the article because if the it moves or is taken down no one will have a clue what it said.

Comment: @EdBeal what causes a wax ring to go bad? Poor fitting when installed #1 in my experience. If a real plumber installed op toilet after the floor was installed it should be dry now and will remain dry until toilet is moved and seal is broken. A good way to insure no motion of toilet happens is caulking. I am in favor of leaving a new install un-caulked  for a while until confidant there is no leak

Comment: House settling / pest damage has been the cause several times that I have repaired. Wax seals usually out last the flooring unless tile then it is usually a style change. You may not have a leak for many years but if it's totally sealed by calk and you do have a leak the damage will be much worse because it went unnoticed.

Comment: @EdBeal  let’s invent a simple sensor that can by placed under the toilet to detect moisture I’ll take 90% of profits for intellectual input. You get 10% for research development design marketing manufacturing distribution

Comment: @Kris - see update

Answer (score 2):

This is an argument that seems to never end. I work for several hotels and in every single room the toilet is caulked. It just plain looks nicer and it helps to stabilize the toilet. Some say that it will hide a leak but that makes limited sense. If a toilet leaks at the base, it's usually related to the flange leaking. Now, if the toilet gets cracked for some reason you might get a leak there but that's rare. Also, what if someone or an animal urinates and it gets underneath the base of the toilet? How would you clean that? Consider just water sitting under there and stagnating. I'm a big fan of caulking around a toilet. Although, you have to do it right. Use tape if you are inexperienced and don't buy anything cheap.

If you do choose to caulk, use a 100% silicone mold-resistant caulk like GE.

[image]

Comment: I agree it looks better and help stabilize but several inches in the back should be left open especially if wood based sub flooring. I have repaired homes that were sealed well the leak went through the floor rotted it and the joists it ended up being a large repair that if they would left a few inches open in the back the leak would have been found and repaired instead of the wall, underlayment , decking and 2 joists. This was the worst one but I have done several that the underlayment was ruined.